# If a set is closed in $\mathbb{R^{+}}$ then it's closed in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

I know a set is closed if it contains all it's limit points. It sounds like if it contains all it's limit points in $\mathbb{R^{+}}$ then it will contain all it's limit points in $\mathbb{R}$, but I have no clue about the proof.

Comment: Take $\mathbb{R}^+$ itself.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott what definition of $\mathbb{R}^+$ do you use? I read the OP's question as using $\mathbb{R}^+ = (0,\infty) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @ClementC.: I was thinking of the two-point compactification (extended real line), but you’re almost certainly right that it’s simply the positive reals.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Fair enough. The OP should probably clarify, the notation is only semi-standard.

Comment: @ClementC. Thanks for your answers. The definition I'm currently using is $\mathbb{R^{+}}$ = [0, $\infty$)

Comment: @dan_rog Thank you for confirming this. As Hanul Jeon commented above, then consider the fact that $(0,\infty)$ is closed in itself ($X$ is always closed for a topology on $X$), but it's obviously not in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @ClementC. Just to make sure I'm understanding the whole idea: (0,$\infty$) is closed in (0,$\infty$), but it's not closed in [0,$\infty$). What I'm trying to prove is that if $\mathbb{X}$ is closed in [0,$\infty$), then it should be closed in $\mathbb{R}$. However, I think that's just what freakish posted.

Comment: @dan_rog sorry, I missed the fact that it's $[0,\infty)$, not $(0,\infty)$. My bad. Yes -- you can prove it directly using the definition of [subspace topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generally consider a situation when $X$ is any topological space and $A\subseteq X$ a subset. Now assume that $F\subseteq A$ is closed in $A$. By the definition of relative (subspace) topology this means that $F=A\cap F'$ for some subset $F'\subseteq X$ closed in $X$. In particular if $A$ is closed in $X$ then $F$ is also closed in $X$ as an intersection of two closed subsets.

On the other hand if $A\subseteq X$ is not closed then clearly $A$ itself is a counterexample, since obviously $A$ is closed in $A$.

So the question boils down to: what is your definition of $\mathbb{R}^+$? If these are positive reals (which would be my first guess) then the answer is "no" because that's not a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$. However if these are non-negative reals then the answer is "yes" because that's a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$.